# Using a Windows Form with Ruby

Tags: windows, ruby, user-interface, dialog

Is it possible to create a form on Windows using Ruby? I have a Ruby script and I would like to have an input form to ask for a user's password, then use this in the rest of my script.

update: I have successfully done this with wxRuby, although it looks ugly. Shoes looks promising, I might look into that if I need to do this again..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recall using [wxRuby](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl) for this a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just something simple, lightweight and fun to program with, I definitely recommend [Shoes](http://shoooes.net/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want something *really* simple, have a look at [**wxCocoaDialog**](http://code.google.com/p/wxcocoadialog/).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use IronRuby:

Scenario 1: straight WinForms:

- See [Mark McFadden's post](http://www.msquaredweb.com/musings/2007/07/test-drive-with-ironruby-and.html)
- See Jimmy Schementi's GitHub [demo app](http://github.com/jschementi/railsconf09/blob/469ec652826cf14844b28cc30921b76c57261e56/8-ardb/app.rb)

Scenario 2: use WPF

- See Ivan Porto Carrero's [IronNails](http://flanders.co.nz/category/wpf/) framework
- See DevX [article](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/36895/1954)

Answer (score 0):

[IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/) runs on the .NET runtime and as such has access to all of the .NET winforms API. It's in development, so it may or may not meet your needs yet.